# Tkinter HTML colorpicker

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm programming a small GUI app that is using the standard colorpicker from Tkinter.
this colorpicker only know's as an in put RGB and it will return Hexcode.

I was wondering is there an colorpicker in Tkinter like an HTML colorpicker (see screenshot)
[image]

Comment: In what way does the standard color picker fail to meet your needs?  It will accept an initial color as either an R,G,B tuple or an HTML color string, and returns the selected color in both formats.

Comment: that is True, but there is no way for me to input an Hex string like in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only colorpicker for tkinter is the *askcolor* from *tkinter.colorchooser*